# Can't connect to GWT project in dev mode from Appcelerator iPhone application

Tags: ios, gwt, ios-simulator, jetty, appcelerator-mobile

i have a GWT application that contains a servlet to handle my Appcelerator mobile application requests.
i binded the GWT application to all IPs using -bindAddress 0.0.0.0 in project x-arguments. 
all works well when i run the Andriod version of the mobile app. But when i run the iOS version the mobile app hangs waiting for connection and eventually cant connect (same thing is happening when i use the iOS simulator).
on the other hand, if i compile the GWT application and deploy it locally under tomcat server Android and iOS connect normally and all works well. moreover, both GWT jetty ports 8888 and 9997 are open on my Mac.

any i dea what might be the problem?